# Elasticsearch remove field performance

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm calling the Update API frequently to remove fields from documents. What is the performance difference between

```
"script" : "ctx._source[\"name_of_field\"] = null"
```

and

```
"script" : "ctx._source.remove(\"name_of_field\")"
```

To my understanding, the second one deletes the document and reindexes the entire document. What is the behaviour of the first one?

Comment: From what I understand of the [update API documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html), both scripts will reindex the whole document.

Comment: A update (even partial) will result in a read, delete, merge of the changes and insert of the modified document.